# UIView addSubView with animation, but allow the old underlying tap

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a UIView `myView` that responds to user taps.
I have added an animated view using:

```
[myView addSubView:animatedView];
```

But now the animated view, is blocking the taps, Since both use the same `frame`
How can I override that easily?

Comment: Have a clear UIView that you put your tap gesture on, add it to `myView` when inserting animatedView use `insertSubview: belowSubview:tapView` or just bring tap view forward afterwards `bringSubviewToFront:tapView`  Not sure if this will work as I think animating the view, the view keeps get put to the front.

Comment: Do u use animation with block? If yes you might want to turn on the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option if u want to interact with your animated view

Comment: This is fine, when the user no need to interact with the events of the animated view. other wise not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can see to you to do that is you declare the UITouchGesture in your views, and when you need to disable the touch in the view you can disable:

An example for a tap:

In your .h file you declare it:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap;
```

And in your .m file

```
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And when you need to disable the tap you can simple:

```
[tap setEnable:NO];
```

or remove it:

```
[yourView removeGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

With that when you need to enable/disable will be easier and also will be easier to you to manage your touchs.